# Pushing a bugfix to production when development is not yet stable

Tags: git, github, development-environment, production-environment

New to git, and don't totally comprehend how everything works, so looking for some detailed instructions...

I have three remotes:

- `origin`, where code changes are made and developers do preliminary testing.  Once those changes seem stable, they're pushed to...
- `staging`, where multiple users (not just those who wrote the code) do further testing.  Once `staging` has been beaten apart and is satisfactory to go in front of customers, I push to...
- `production`, where the app becomes public and customers can use it.

I have changes in my `staging` environment that are not ready to go to `production`, but have an urgent fix that needs to go to `production` now.  How would I go about creating a fix and pushing it to `production` without pushing the unstable changes in `staging`?

I've pushed a few commits to `staging` using this process:

**Get the latest code:**

```
git checkout master
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

**Migrate the database:**

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

**Create a new branch:**

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

(make some changes, test locally and run test suite)

**Commit changes:**

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
```

**Merge changes:**

```
git checkout master
git merge newbranch
```

(test locally to make sure nothing got messed up in the merge)

**Push to repository:**

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
git push origin master
```

**Push to `staging`/dev environment:**

```
git push staging master
```

(Further testing in development area to make sure everything is good to go to production.  Start over if further changes need to be made before pushing.  This loop continues for a while until everything looks good.  Currently, I'm at this stage, with changes that are being tested and are not ready to go to `production` yet.)

**Push to `production`:**

```
git push production master
```

So let's say I create a new branch with a bug fix...how would these steps change to get that bug fix to production without pushing all the unstable changes that are on staging right now?

I've done a decent amount of searching around, and so far have figured out that there is a way to do it, but I am too shaky with git to figure out the commands to use to get there...Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the production repo/branch?  origin/master?

Comment: The production branch is production master

Comment: @AndrewC Yes, my mistake; I meant `checkout`. Oh well, my comment is obsolete now, anyway.

Comment: @COS You write: *without pushing all the unstable changes that are on staging*. Just to clarify: the unstable changes are already in your local `master` branch, and this branch is your most stable branch. Correct?

Comment: @Jubobs Sorry, not sure the answer to your question...Maybe unstable is the wrong word to use.  They're untested changes, and yes they are already in my local master branch.  As far as whether that is the most stable branch, I don't know what you mean by that.  The production branch is the most stable branch right now, but because customers are using it, I can't risk sending the untested changes in staging to production just to get a small bug fix in there.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @COS Yes, I understand. Also, are you the only developer on the project?

Comment: @Jubobs Mostly yes, unfortunately.  Occasionally, though, there is another developer who contributes, which is why I use this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Don't pollute your `master` branch with untested stuff

You write that you routinely push your local `master` branch to your staging server; if so, that implies that you're not 100% sure that what's on `master` is ready for production. But isn't `master` supposed to be your most stable local branch? Or do you have an even more stable (local) branch?

If your local `master` is indeed meant to be your most stable branch, you are wrong to merge untested/experimental stuff (e.g. from `newbranch`) in `master` *before* testing that everything works on your `origin` and `staging` servers; you are "polluting" your local `master` branch with unproven stuff! Not good.

### A suggestion for fixing the immediate problem

At the very least, you should switch to a workflow that doesn't pollute your local `master` branch.

Here is an idea. Create a new local branch called `develop` pointing to the current tip of `master`.

```
git branch develop master
```

Then, under the assumption that `origin/master` is behind your local `master` branch, reset your local `master` branch to its last stable state (the current production state):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard production/master
```

Now, create and checkout a `bugfix` branch that points to the same commit as `master`  does:

```
git checkout -b bugfix
```

Then

1. Make some commits on `bugfix` to fix the bug.
2. Push your `bugfix` branch to the `master` branch in your `origin` server:

   ```
    git push origin bugfix:master
   ```

   Force push if you have to.
3. As long as you're not satisfied with the results on your `origin` server, go back to step 1.
4. Once you're satisfied with what you see on your `origin` server, push your `bugfix` branch to the `master` branch in your `staging` server

   ```
   git push staging bugfix:master
   ```

   Force push if you have to.
5. As long as you're not satisfied with the results on your `staging` server, go back to step 1.

Finally, merge `bugfix` into `master`, delete it, and push `master` to your `production` remote:

```
git checkout master
git merge bugfix
git branch -d bugfix
git push production master
```

Now that you have deployed the bugfix, it's time to bring your `develop` branch up to date:

```
git checkout develop
git merge master
```

Your `develop` branch now contains the bugfix. You can continue developing your new features on it.

### A suggestion for improving your workflow

Do all development on `develop`. If you want to, use intermediate feature branches, that you then merge into `develop`. When you're ready to test the new stuff,

1. Push `develop` to the `master` branch in your `origin` server; make sure everything works there.
2. Push `develop` to the `master` branch in your `staging` server; make sure everything works there.
3. Merge `develop` into `master`.
4. Push `master` to the `production` server.

Comment: I have three remotes: Origin, Staging and Production.  Production is the most stable branch, and is available for our customers to use.  On all servers, the branch that is deployed is called master.

Comment: @COS I just saw your comment. What is the purpose of origin, if not for production? Is it just used as a backup?

Comment: Code changes are made to origin (a testing environment for developers to test).  Once they seem stable, they're published to staging for further testing (by multiple users, not just the ones writing the code), then they are published to production for customer use.

Comment: @COS Ok. I'll amend my answer accordingly. You should edit your question to explain what each server is used for.

Comment: master is up to date with origin/master...how might that change things? Or does it?

Comment: Also maybe I don't fully understand git reset --hard, but won't that get rid of all the changes that are already on staging? How would I get them back?

Comment: `reset --hard` will delete all unstaged and uncommitted local changes (if any) and move the `master` reference to an earlier commit; that operation alone won't affect what's on the staging server.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience, @Jubobs.  That was exactly what I needed. I was nervous to try, but it did the trick! Also, will take your advice and work on develop branch.

Answer (score 1):

You have two basic options:

1. Create a hotfix branch off of your current production release, and merge it back with that branch once you've created, cherry-picked, or merged in your hotfix patches. For example, assuming *master* is your production branch:

   ```
   git checkout -b hotfix/name-of-bug master
   # code, hack, edit
   git commit -am 'Apply hotfix for bug X.'

   # Make sure the merge resolves as a fast-forward by rebasing.
   # Skip this if you don't care about enforcing linear history.
   git rebase master

   git checkout master
   git merge hotfix/name-of-bug master
   git push
   ```
2. Cherry-pick specific commits to your master branch. For example, if you want to pull in commit 7c199758 from anywhere in your repository:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git cherry-pick 7c199758
   git push
   ```

I would use a hotfix branch if you have multiple commits or an actual line of development to merge, while cherry-picking is often the right way to go if you only want a small handful of very atomic commits.